# How to define a regex for (arg_1, arg_2, ..., arg_n) in java and use it to split a string?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string that has names of couple of methods and classes in them and other information that I am trying to extract.  The methods and classes are separated by : which is pretty straight forward.For methods, I only need the names and not the parameters. I am trying to define a regex to represent (...) where ... represents anything.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
String str = "M:org.apache.commons.math3.genetics.CycleCrossover:mate(org.apache.commons.math3.genetics.AbstractListChromosome,org.apache.commons.math3.genetics.AbstractListChromosome) (O)java.util.HashSet:<init>(int)";
String[] arr = line.split(":|[(&&[a-z|A-Z]&&)]");
```

This will give me the following:

```
M
org.apache.commons.math3.genetics.CycleCrossover
mate(org.apache.commons.math3.genetics.AbstractListChromosome,org.apache.commons.math3.genetics.AbstractListChromosome) (O)java.util.HashSet
<init>(int)
```

which is technically the same as using only ':'
I have tried a variety of different patterns but the closet that I got to is the following:

```
String[] arr = line.split(":| |[(]|[)]");
```

which produces:

```
M
org.apache.commons.math3.genetics.CycleCrossover
mate
org.apache.commons.math3.genetics.AbstractListChromosome,org.apache.commons.math3.genetics.AbstractListChromosome


O
java.util.HashSet
<init>
int
```

finally what I am trying to get is;

```
M
org.apache.commons.math3.genetics.CycleCrossover
mate

java.util.HashSet
<init>
```

Comment: Well, you could try expression `:|\([^\)]*\)` which means "a colon or (a sequence of opening parenthesis, anything not a closing parenthesis and a closing parenthesis)". - However, note that code often is an irregular problem space so regular expressions have their limits in parsing code. It's often advisable to try and parse code with a proper parser.

Comment: I do not know much about parsing codes, could you please point me to a right parser to use?

Comment: Well, it depends on what exactly you want to parse but ANTLR would be a good point to start. It comes with quite a list of grammars for many languages already but you could even add your own if required.

Comment: Thank you! I realized my input always will be of the same pattern, but I will make a note of ANTLR too, for the next version of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you give this a try:

```
String[] arr = str.split("(\\((.*?)\\))|:|  |[(]|[)]");
```

should look like this now:

```
M
org.apache.commons.math3.genetics.CycleCrossover
mate
 
java.util.HashSet
<init>
```

`\\(` and `)//` which will match `()`. For `(.*?)`, the `.*?` will match any character zero or anything and the `()` is the group.

Comment: Thank you, I realized my problem was that I wasn’t putting that *? After . 
Thanks for explaining it.